# Как создать ассоциативный массив указателей на объекты С++?

Tags: c++, qt5, map

Пишу на QT 5.10.
Есть некий протокол обмена для передачи данных. Каждое сообщение содержит заголовок и тело сообщения. Этот протокол инкапсулирует в себе другой протокол, который тоже содержит свой заголовок и данные, в этом внутреннем протоколе много различных типов блоков, данные которых собираются и разбираются уникальным образом. Что за тип сообщения - можно определить по двум полям в заголовке, а способ обработки по третьему полю. Напрашивается наследование: базовый класс внешнего протокола<-базовый класс внутреннего протокола<-дочерний класс конкретного сообщения. Тут проблем не возникло.
Чтобы не писать гигантские switch...case... (всё же сотни вариантов сообщений) - я решил создать ассоциативный массив объектов обработчиков блоков данных. Каждый обработчик должен присутствовать в одном экземпляре и создать класс-контроллер в конструкторе которого будет создан весь ассоциативный массив объектов, и нужный обработчик потомок будет вызываться по уникальному ключу, извлечённому из заголовка блока, со своими виртуальными методами. Вот тут возникла проблема: на указатель на базовый класс в ассоциативном массиве возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
D:\MyPrograms\RapidVHF\RapidVHF\frameselector.h:19: ошибка: 'RAP1' was not declared in this scope
 map<uint32_t, RAP1*> framemap;
               ^
```

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
#ifndef FRAMESELECTOR_H
#define FRAMESELECTOR_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
//#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "usertypes.h"
#include "rap1.h"
//#include "datatomodem.h"
//#include "pskotasetframe.h"

using namespace std;

class FrameSelector
{
private:
    map<uint32_t,  unique_ptr<RAP1> > framemap; //ошибка возникает и здесь
    //map<uint32_t, RAP1*> framemap;            // и здесь
public:
    FrameSelector(Ui::MainWindow *UI);
    ~FrameSelector();
    bool MakeFrame(uint8_t *pFrame = nullptr);
    bool CheckFrame(uint8_t *pFrame = nullptr);
};

#endif // FRAMESELECTOR_H
```

Собственно описание базового класса внутреннего протокола

```
#ifndef RAP1_H
#define RAP1_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <QString>
#include <QComboBox>
#include "ripc.h"
#include "usertypes.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class RAP1 : public RIPC
{
protected:
    static uint8_t SequenceNumber;
    const int shGroupID = 20;
    const int shMessageID = 22;
    const int shMsgSequenceNum = 24;
    const int shMsgType = 25;
    const int shData = 26;
public:
    RAP1(Ui::MainWindow *UI);
    virtual ~RAP1();
    bool FillHeader(uint8_t* pFrame);
    QString toTakeDigitDataFromComboBox(QComboBox *pComboBox);
    virtual bool FillFrame(uint8_t *pFrame) = 0;
    virtual void ExtractData(uint8_t *pFrame) = 0;
};

#endif // RAP1_H
```

Ну и реализации некоторых методов:

```
FrameSelector::FrameSelector(Ui::MainWindow *UI)
{
    uint32_t keyid = MODEM_DATA * 65536 + SEND_DATA_TO_MODEM;
    framemap.insert(pair<uint32_t,unique_ptr<RAP1> >(keyid, unique_ptr<DataToModem>(new DataToModem(UI))));
    keyid = WAVEFORM_CONFIGURATION * 65536 + PSK_OTA_SET;
    framemap.insert(pair<uint32_t,unique_ptr<RAP1> >(keyid, unique_ptr<PskOtaSetFrame>(new PskOtaSetFrame(UI))));
}

RAP1::RAP1(Ui::MainWindow *UI) : RIPC(UI)
{}

RAP1::~RAP1()
{}
```

P.S. со shared_ptr тоже не работает.

Дополнение:

```
#ifndef RIPC_H
#define RIPC_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include "framecontainer.h"
#include "ccitt_crc16.h"
```

//----------

```
#ifndef FRAMECONTAINER_H
#define FRAMECONTAINER_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <memory>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```

//----------

```
#ifndef USERTYPES_H
#define USERTYPES_H

#include <stdint.h>
```

/------
ui_mainwindow.h генерируется самой средой

```
#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QComboBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QFrame>
#include <QtWidgets/QGridLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QGroupBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QLineEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QProgressBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QRadioButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
#include <QtWidgets/QSpinBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QTabWidget>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это говорит о том, что у вас в коде возникло циклическое включение заголовочных файлов. Include guards разорвали этот цикл, но в результате вы получили "необъяснимую" ошибку: вроде заголовочный файл `rap1.h` включен, а все равно компилятор не знает, что такое `RAP1`.

Из того, что вы пока привели, не видно, как возник цикл, но он есть.

Избавляйтесь от циклического включения. Возможно, что для этого в одном из заголовочных файлов придется сделать только предварительные объявления каких-то классов. А возможно и нет - пока трудно судить.

Comment: Возможно, также, что в списке путей присутствует еще один файл с именем  `rap1.h` и включается не тот файл, который ожидает Виктор.

Comment: @Chorkov: Возможно, но вряд ли. Скорее всего, какой-нибудь `ripc.h` включает `frameselector.h` явно или опосредованно.

Comment: Циклическая ссылка - вряд ли. Во первых я её искал, но не нашёл, а во вторых если в класс FrameSelector просто вставить указатель: RAP1 *rap; - то его компилятор принимает без возмущений. Я знаю, что если просто создавать динамический массив объектов - то требуется, чтобы у класса был конструктор по умолчанию, но здесь вроде не тот случай. А во вторых RAP1 - это абстрактный класс, но на создвние указателя это не должно влиять.

Comment: @Виктор: Вы что-то выдумываете. "Создание указателя" здесь не причем. Причем здесь простая объявленность идентификатора `RAP1`. Если этот идентификатор компилятору не известен, то никакого указателя вы объявить не сможете. Если вам на ваш исходный вариант компилятор выдает "ошибка: 'RAP1' was not declared in this scope", то и на  `RAP1 *rap;` в классе вы получите ту же ошибку.

Comment: Но я ведь попробовал и не получил. Меня это самого удивляет

Comment: @Виктор: Это значит, что вы нас обманываете в тексте вопроса. Вы говорите, что вариант `map<uint32_t, RAP1*>` выдает ошибку, которую вы процитировали в вопросе, но при этом `RAP1 *rap;` компилируется успешно? Так не бывает. Это невозможно. Приводите реальный код и реальные сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Неужели Вы думаете,  что я сказки рассказываю!? Может всё таки ошибка в диагнозе?

Comment: Нет, это невозможно в принципе, независимо от диагноза. Компилятор не может в одной строчке говорить, что не знает идентификатора `RAP1` вообще, а в другой в том же контексте - спокойно принимать этот идентификатор. Ошибка тут в том, что вы, как часто бывает, "привели не тот код", "исправили, но забыли поправить здесь", "неточно скопипастили", "такая ошибка была вчера, а сегодня уже нет" или еще что-то в этом роде. Мы не телепаты, и нас отсюда не видно, что именно вы там компилируете.

Comment: Ладно, если у коллег других идей нет - придётся самому копать. Решу - рассажу как.

Comment: @Виктор: Лучше приведите список `#include` из `ripc.h`, `usertypes.h`, `ui_mainwindow.h`

Comment: Дополнил сведения в описание вопроса

Comment: Вынужден прерваться примерно на сутки...

Comment: Там нигде в проекте не дублируются RAP1_H guard из заголовков ? Я так один раз много времени убил не понимая что не так, а когда нашёл - перешёл на использование `#pragma once`. Не обязательно RAP1_H, любой guard из заголовков (не уникальный) приводит к удивительным вещам

Comment: Исправилось, после изменения порядка компиляции в файле *.pro. Странное поведение вчера с указателем навело на эту мысль. Если постепенно раскомментировать заголовочные файлы и каждый раз билдить - то компиляция проходит успешно, а если пересобрать всё - то ошибка снова вылезала. Так что ошибка всё же была в диагнозе , в этом конкретном случае, но не спорю, что могла бы быть и там, где мне указывали. Всем спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен, что в большинстве случаев, причиной такой ошибки компиляции служит циклическая ссылка на заголовочный файл, как указали коллеги в первом ответе. Однако в этом конкретном случае на возникновение ошибки повлиял порядок компиляции файлов. Его изменение в файле проекта (с расширением *.pro) устранило эту ошибку.